# Is corporate housing provided as part of a relocation package tax-deductible?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, relocation

I have a question about **Publication 521 (Moving Expenses)**.

The publication indicates that lodging during the move is a deductible expense.

When we moved, my employer paid for us to stay in a hotel room for a couple weeks before we found a new home. They are reporting the cost of that stay on my W-2 ("Relocation Taxable"). Is this lodging that I can deduct, or does the rule only refer to hotels that we stayed in while traveling from City A to City B?

We only stayed in the corporate housing during our relocation, so I don't think it falls into [this code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/119?quicktabs_8=1#quicktabs-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deductible lodging is only during the move itself, i.e.: if you're driving cross country and staying in hotels on the way - these are deductible.